# Use encryption and decryption in iphone App and WebService

Tags: ios, web-services, encryption, cryptography

I am building an application which is talking to my .Net WebService. Application is transmitting some sensitive client information to my WebService which I want to encrypt before I wrap it in the SOAP Envelop. And web service will decrypt it on the other side before using it.

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this. I know .Net has some security which allow you to do some authentication and encryption but I dont want to go to that path at this stage, as I want to make data secure going to and from the iOS device to my webservice.

If any tutorial or example exists please let me know as this is first time I am using encryption decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an HTTPS connection. This will encrypt your entire connection, and it's trivial to use and built in to both the iPhone and .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but for that I have to secure the websevice and have to buy SSL certificate. Any other option ...

Comment: @microchip78 SSL certificates are extremely cheap these days; this shouldn't be a barrier to doing it the right way. I'm not sure what you mean by "secure the webservice" - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

AES is available on pretty much every platform. What you have to do is to make sure that everything else is the same on both platforms:
 1.The same mode; use either CBC or CTR mode. 
2.The same IV; set it explicitly, don't use the default because it will often be different on different systems. 
3.The same key; obvious, but they need to be the same at the byte level because text can be encoded differently on different systems. Explicitly state the encoding you are using. 
4.The same padding; for AES use PKCS7, again don't rely on the default which may be different on different systems.

Whatever you chose do set things explicitly and don't rely on defaults. Defaults can differ between systems and any difference will cause decryption to fail.